# How can I reload pages with Ctrl + Shift + R from FireBug?

Tags: firefox, firebug, reload

Often I'm using firebug when I switch to my code. When I switch back firebug is still the active pane so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> doesn't reload the page. I have to click in the main pane (or tab 3 times), then reload. It only takes a second, but that time really adds up, and it slows the flow of my coding.

Is there an extension that will allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page even if the firebug pane is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd. 
But note that [the alternative to CTRL-SHIFT-R is CTRL-F5](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation) that also works when Firebug has been focused.

Florent

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that the shortcut is currently used to clear the console. You can simply change it within the [Firebug Shortcut Bindings](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Shortcut_Bindings) dialog to something else. After that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> should work as expected again.

I created [issue 7190](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7190) to resolve this conflict and [fixed it](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/commit/30b80e7cb0d1173b9d49edd0e65ee552c53e77b5) by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> instead.